# Vim - adjust .tex lines to 80 columns respecting commands

Tags: vim, latex

I have defined a command in my `tex.vim` as

```
setlocal tw=80
:map <F4> {gq}
```

which adjusts the current paragraph to 80 or less columns. However, while this recognizes comments and leaves them as they are, it doesn't recognize commands. Although it doesn't make a difference compiling, I like to keep my tables and equations well indented and organized, which means I have to be careful when using `{gq}`. Is there a way to define a command that is aware of this kind of content and leaves commands as they are?

**EDIT**

Example!
Consider the following code

```
Some generic text to introduce an Eq.: 
\begin{equation}
y =  ax + b,
\end{equation}
after which there is this long text that should not be more than some $x$ columns but it is, so it should be cut.
```

After using the command to adjust this paragraph to an 80-columns maximum I'd expect this to happen (emacs does it like this)

```
Some generic text to introduce an Eq.: 
\begin{equation}
y =  ax + b,
\end{equation}
after which there is this long text that should not be more than some 
$x$ columns but it is, so it should be cut.
```

However, with my pre-defined command I get this:

```
Some generic text to introduce an Eq.: \begin{equation} y =  ax + b,
\end{equation} after which there is this long text that should not be more than
some $x$ columns but it is, so it should be cut.
```

Which is not what I want.

Cheers

Comment: ACan you put some sample TeX code and expected output? That might help me to understand what you wanted. I can answer

Comment: @SibiCoder just added an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can **replace text**

```
 :%s/.\{80\}/&\r/g
```

This will put a new line after 80th character in all lines, thereby splitting them.

If you want this to be done automatically while saving, you can use `autocommand` for that.

```
 :au BufWritePre *.* :%s/.\{80\}/&\r/g
```

Put this line in your `~/.vimrc` file.

Now, whenever you save your file, text after 80th column will be moved to next line.

(There are several other ways to do it as well!)

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I'm looking for. This sometimes cuts words in the middle and even if that wasn't a problem it doesn't adjust the paragraphs so well as `{gq}`.

Comment: For the example you gave, the expected output is got. When givetwo or three complex examples, so that I can rewrite miy code?